# ffmpeg make 1s of 240fps video from 4s of 60fps?

Tags: ffmpeg, slowmotion, fps

How can I use ffmpeg to create 1 second of 240fps from every 4 seconds of 60fps video?

I see only seen questions asking for the opposite.

#### Background

Our drone is only able to capture 60fps, but if we move it around slowly and compress 4 seconds into 1 second then we should make a "slow motion" video. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic command would be

```
ffmpeg -i 60fps.mp4 -vf "settb=1/240,setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/4,fps=240" out.mp4
```

I assume audio is absent or immaterial.